# Question about fibres

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the fibre of $x$ over some binary relation $R$ be the set of $y$ such that $xRy$. Question: Is the following claim true?

> $\forall R \forall X \exists x$ the fibre of $x$ over $R$ is $X$.

Comment: The claim in the box is obviously false. Are you sure you wrote down the question correctly?

Answer (score 2):

As stated, $X$ may not have anything to do with $R$, so as stated this is immediately not true (e.g. $R$ may be about numbers , but $X$ could be a set of fruits)

It would be a little more interesting if we say that $R$ is defined over $X$, i.e. if $R \subseteq X \times X$

But even then, the statement is not true. Counterexample:

$X = \{ 1 \}$ (anything not empty)

$R = \{ \}$